# CUDA Global Function Not Adding Array Values Correctly for Some Indexes

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, nvcc

I am working through this CUDA [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzXjRFL-gjo&list=PLKK11Ligqititws0ZOoGk3SW-TZCar4dK&index=4) on Youtube. The code is provided in the second half of the video. It's a simple CUDA program to add the elements of two arrays. So if we had a first array called `a` and a second called `b` the final value of `a[i]` would be:

```
a[i] += b[i];
```

The problem is, no matter what I do. The first four elements of the final output are always bizarre numbers. The program creates random inputs for the arrays of 0 to 1000. This means that the final output value at each index should be between zero and 2000. However, regardless of the random seed, the program always outputs a combination of absurdly large (out of range) numbers or zeros for the first four results.

For indexes greater than 3, the outputs seem to be find. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

__global__ void AddInts( int *a, int *b, int count){
  int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x +threadIdx.x;
  if (id < count){
    a[id] += b[id];
  }
}

int main(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int count = 100;
  int *h_a = new int[count];
  int *h_b = new int[count];

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){ // Populating array with 100 random values
    h_a[i] = rand() % 1000; // elements in range 0 to 1000
    h_b[i] = rand() % 1000;
  }

  cout << "Prior to addition:" << endl;
  for (int i =0; i < 10; i++){ // Print out the first five of each
    cout << h_a[i] << " " << h_b[i] << endl;
  }

  int *d_a, *d_b; //device copies of those arrays

  if(cudaMalloc(&d_a, sizeof(int) * count) != cudaSuccess) // malloc for cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost
  {
    cout<<"Nope!";
    return -1;
  }
  if(cudaMalloc(&d_b, sizeof(int) * count) != cudaSuccess)
  {
    cout<<"Nope!";
    cudaFree(d_a);
    return -2;
  }

  if(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, sizeof(int) * count, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
  {
    cout << "Could not copy!" << endl;
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    return -3;
  }
  if(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, sizeof(int) * count, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
  {
    cout << "Could not copy!" << endl;
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_a);
    return -4;
  }

  AddInts<<<count / 256 +1, 256>>>(d_a, d_b, count);

  if(cudaMemcpy(h_a, d_a, sizeof(int) * count, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)!= cudaSuccess)   //magic of int division
  { // copy from device back to host
    delete[]h_a;
    delete[]h_b;
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cout << "Error: Copy data back to host failed" << endl;
    return -5;
  }
  delete[]h_a;
  delete[]h_b;
  cudaFree(d_a);
  cudaFree(d_b);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout<< "It's " << h_a[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled with:

```
nvcc threads_blocks_grids.cu -o threads
```

The result of `nvcc -version` is:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

And here is my output:

```
Prior to addition:
771 177
312 257
303 5
291 819
735 359
538 404
718 300
540 943
598 456
619 180
It's 42984048
It's 0
It's 42992112
It's 0
It's 1094
It's 942
It's 1018
It's 1483
It's 1054
It's 799
```

Answer (score 1):

You deleted host arrays before printing. This has an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you use  <= C++11, and implementation defined bahavior for > C++11.

If you move the print part up, it should be solved.